# get different datetime when shell script is executing

Tags: shell, unix, ksh

i have shell script(ksh) which writes files to xxxx unix directory through SPOOL from oracle table x.

Table x having column having seq_no.The file should get generated for different seeq_no.

E.G.

```
table x data

seq_no,a,b,c
1,2,3,4
1,5,6,7
1,8,9,10
2,1,2,3
2,4,5,6
2,7,8,9
```

The file name = test_${STAMP}.csv

In this case two files with different timstamp should get generated as we have 2 different seq_no in table x.

When the script runs STAMP = date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S variable will hold only one value.So my first file is getting over writen by second.

Please tell me how can i find current datetime when the shell script is in execution condition itself.

Comment: So what is your desired output? Where do the dates come from? Are you expecting the script to be slow enough that the time changes by a second while it is running?

Comment: You can split the outputfile using the seq_no after Oracle finished. Maybe you want to make the filnames unique by adding the seq_no in the filename ?

Answer (score 0):

If I get your question correctly, you need to have separate files each having records for a specific sequence number only.

If you can change the approach then you can try something as below:

1. spool another file, lets say `seq_file`, to query distinct seq nos.

   ```
    Content of seq_file:
   1
   2
   3
   5
   ```
2. Iterate on each line of `seq_file` and `grep "^${seq},"` and redirect output to required file, may be you can calculate STAMP2 variable to use in final file name.

   ```
   while read seq
   do
      STAMP2=`date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S`
      grep "^${seq}," test_${STAMP}.csv >> ${seq}_$STAMP2
   done<seq_file
   ```

Comment: You can skip step1 and run this `cat file | awk -F ',' '{print $1}' | sort -u> seq_file`